# Kala U bass going from newer round wound to thunderstruck strings

Tags: ukulele

Can u remove the round wound strings , save them for later and throw on thunderstruck black strings to see what they sound like . I just dont want to waste the round wounds.

Comment: It happens with most basses. Take the strings off, boil them, save them for later.

Comment: @Tim Boil them?

Comment: It gets rid of grease, dirt etc., and makes the strings to some extent, re-usable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with a couple of “but”s...

You should have enough length on the round wounds to take them off and put them back in again. The other way would definitely work as the synth-rubber strings (the Pahoehoes Kala uses, Thunderguts, etc) stretch forever and a day.

You’ll need a new nut. Thunderguts have a much larger diameter than roundwounds. You may be able to straight swap Pahoehoes for roundwounds. I’d expect Pahoehoes to also need a new nut, but a Pahoehoe nut and a roundwound nut I have from Kala appear to be the same. Kala may have mismarked one of the ones they sent me

Intonation will likely be off with the new strings (if it’s not with the old ones). This may or may not make a difference if you just play in the low frets and not up the fretboard. Easily solved by removing the frets ;)